# Words represents sounds - stick hitting road & noise in a radio station

Tags: word-choice, word-request

There are some sounds that is represented by words. Like -

> 1. The door **creaked** open.
> 2. The **tick tick** of the wall clock.

***Tick tick*** and ***creak*** represent the sound. I am looking for such words which represent sounds like these -

1. An old man while walking hitting his walking stick against the hard pitch road - Looking for a word which represents the sound of the stick hitting the hard road.
2. A word which represents the sound of noise in a radio station.

Comment: What material is the walking stick made of?

Comment: @Bobthezealot wooden stick.

Comment: Is the stick hollow or not?

Comment: @Bobthezealot it's solid. like all wooden walking stick.

Comment: Is it real wood or fake wood?

Comment: For #2, what kind of noise are you talking about? What causes it? Where does it happen in the station? How much noise is there? What's the context?

Comment: @Bobthezealot Real

Comment: @EsotericScreenName When we play a radio we turn the nob to adjust the channel. Even so the device catches the station, the sound it emits are sometimes mixed with noise - sometimes with more noise and sometimes with less noise. I am asking for in general noise.

Answer (score 1):

For the first request, since you've said *hit* (which makes me think that some force is being used), I'd say *[thump](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thump)*, *[thud](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/thud)*, *[thunk](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/thunk)* or *[clunk](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/clunk)*, with the first two being preferred (unless the stick is extremely heavy and both it and the road are very hard). If the striking against the ground is light, I recommend *[tap](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tap)* (def. 10). These are [onomatopoeia](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/onomatopoeia): words created to resemble and represent certain sounds. The examples of *creak* and *tick* in your question are the same sort of words.

The word representing the noise between radio stations is *[hiss](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hiss)* (see noun def. 1.2). This is also an onomatopoeic word, representing the quality or description of the sound. The name of the noise is *[static](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/static)*, but that word is not onomatopoeic, so it doesn't tell us how the noise sounds.

Answer (score 1):

**Walking stick:**

*clack, clack, clack*

*tap, tap, tap*

**Radio:**

*hiss*

*BZZZZ*